# Альтернатива циклу на PHP

Tags: php, sql, циклы

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос в следующем:  В системе постоянно требуется обновление базы данных до самой актуальной версии. Программа работает с АПИ.
Вытягивается массив данных с сайта партнерки, это примерно 3000 записей.
В цикле по каждому товару собирается информация для записи в базу данных(Собирается строка для записи в базу данных). 
То есть это 3000 итераций. 
Все это выполняется больше минуты, хотя сам запрос работает меньше секунды.

**Значит проблема с циклом.**

Не знаю как разрешить эту проблему, на ум приходит только рекурсия, но насколько я знаю в таких задачах рекурсия не даст никакого выиграша. 
Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста!)

Comment: рекурсия медленнее цикла. Вместо циклов можно использовать встроенные функции (array_map, array_walk, и т.п., зависит от задач), но будет ли существенный прирост скорости, я лично не знаю.

Comment: рекурсия не медленее цикла (если все правильно писать). Да, может чуть больше памяти скушать, или переполнить стек, но не затормозить программу.

Проблема то не в цикле, а в теле цикла. Вот его бы и увидеть (хотя бы схематически - есть ли http запросы, есть ли сохранения в базу)

Comment: очереди вам в помощь. либо можно разделить запросы и не сразу тянуть все 3000 товаров, а по 100. В любом из вариантов придется думать о том, какой товар уже  обновлен и когда его обновлять в следующий раз.

Comment: В том то и дело что нет ни запросов в базу ни запросов к апи на этом этапе, все что делается это дописывание строки для записи в базу.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо за ответ. А что вы скажете на счёт циклов и встроенных функций? Что быстрее?

Comment: так в цикле просто конкатенируется строка? И она наверно очень большая?

Comment: @KoVadim, да так и есть

Comment: попробуйте завести массив и добавлять строки в него с помощью array_push вместо простой конкатенации. А потом,  в самом конце одним join преобразуете в большую строку.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за совет, попробую!

Comment: @Nataly я не уверен, что это будет решением, но всё же попробуйте вместо конкатенации использовать массив - т.е., в цикле собирать значения в массив, а за пределами цикла преобразовать массив в строку с помощью join().

Answer (score 0):

можно попробовать уменьшить сложность итерации, отрефакторить код, вынести повторяющиеся действия; можно попробовать распараллелить таким образом, чтобы программа обрабатывала 3000 записей не в одном потоке, а по 500 в нескольких (в этом варианте нужно быть внимательным с критической секцией).